Can I define different global styles for QListWidgetItems
I am using a global qss stylesheet for my PyQt5 application.
Now I have different types of QListWidgetItem which require different styles and would like to do this with a single qss file.
A QObject has the nice features setObjectName() or setProperty which do exactly what I need, e.g.
button = QPushButton('Something')
button.setObjectName('Name')

can be referenced in the qss stylesheet file as
QPushButton#Name {...}

However, a QListWidgetItem is no QObject, therefore, this neat solution is not available.
My question is:
Is there a way to obtain a similar behaviour for a QListWidgetItem using a single stylesheet file?
Defining the styles manually within the application is of course always a possibilty, but I am still hoping for a clean solution.

Qt Style Sheets can only style QWidget subclasses. Item objects of high level classes such as QListWidget are just "data pointers/containers" and, as such, cannot be styled. The only way to individually alter the appearance of items in item views, based on certain parameters (displayed value, etc.) is through item delegates.
